How to perform a find-replace operation from the cursor position to EOF
How to perform a find-replace operation in Neovim from the cursor position to the end of the file (EOF), as Ex command
:%s/Hi/Hello/g

will write entire document file instead of from current cursor position
Help out sincerely

Try this:
:.,$s/Hi/Hello/g

Explanation,
:'.,$s specifies the range of substitute starting from the current line, which is represented by . to the end of the file (EOF) $.
This substitute command replaces occurrences of "Hi" with "Hello" at the end of the file from the current line. The g at the end of the command makes the replacement global on each line, meaning it will replace all occurrences of "Hi" on each line within the specified range, not just the first one.
